# Select first seven characters or originated lead sub source from loans where originated lead subsource is not null, limit 10

Tags: mysql

This is the query I have so far but it isn't returning the first 7 characters but instead the last 7. How would I correct this? This is for MySql.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Lead_Sub_Source__c, 0 - 7) AS leadsubsource
  FROM loan__Loan_Account__c
 WHERE Lead_Sub_Source__c IS NOT NULL
 LIMIT 10
```

Comment: The function and the meaning of its parameters is documented here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring Have a look.

Answer (score 1):

try a comma instead of a dash:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Lead_Sub_Source__c, 1, 7) AS leadsubsource FROM loan__Loan_Account__c WHERE Lead_Sub_Source__c IS NOT NULL LIMIT 10
```